# IE8 jquery calls not returning right when using IP instead of localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, ip, localhost

I have a jquery ajax call

```
$.get("http://localhost:82/store-app/public/Index/getstylinginfo"
```

When I run it from IE using local host it works fine. but when I try to run it using IE using my ip address it doesnt fetch the data . any idea what I may be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localhost` and your IP address are not the same domain. They may be the same machine; one may even point to the other, but they are separate domains, and so you cannot access one from the other because of the Same Origin Policy.

To avoid coming up against the Same Origin Policy, you must use the same domain, protocol and port as in the original document.

Comment: but I want to access the site deployed on my localmachine using apache server accessible on some other machines on the network ? any idea how I can get this.

Comment: You'll have to use one of the methods for cross-domain data. JSONP is the simplest.

Comment: how ? setting up a virtual host ?